# Using one notebook to open second notebook and execute sql query in Databricks that will create table

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

My task is to create in Databricks one notebook with python query that will open another notebook with sql query.

First notebook - 1note:

```
%python
%run "/folder/2note"
```

Second notebook - 2note:

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dw`.`test` (id INT,name STRING,nyear SHORT)
```

I was searching but still I don't know if it is possible, that first notebook active second notebook to create table.

I tried to run that query but it doesn't create any table. There aren't any errors just no resault.

Comment: Try this: create a function in the second notebook like `def createTable(): spark.sql(your sql query with DDL)`, then in the first notebook after the run command, call this function `createTable()` - This is untested but worth trying

Comment: @anky Hey I tried this but it's not creating any table. I am not sure if I am doing this right:
spark.sql(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dw`.`test` (id INT,name STRING,nyear SHORT) USING DELTA)

Comment: Put the sql query as a string

Comment: @anky It works when I use it without "def createTable():" when I am trying to define this function it's giving me no resault and it's still not creating any function. Maybe I am doing something wrong I am still new to this enviroment but when I use this:
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dw.test (id INT,name STRING,nyear SHORT) USING DELTA") it is creating me table so without defining function it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%run` is used to pull code from the notebook with the same language. If you need to run notebook with another language, you can use `dbutils.notebook.run` function (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api) for all details)